# Error compiling with make

Tags: 13.04, dell, compiling, inspiron, make

when I tried to compile John the Ripper on my computer
a dell inspiron 1501 running 13.04
i ran the command
make
make clean generic
i get the error

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generic.h] Error 1`

How do I fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing libssl-dev package installed.

If what you're trying to compile is among the packages available for Ubuntu but say, you want a newer version, you might want to install all build prerequisites with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep john
```

to satisfy build dependencies for the "john" package.

Otherwise you need to check for build dependencies manually. Often the './configure' command gives you enough information.

Comment: installing `libssl-dev` helped will select as answer in 3 minutes

Comment: Thanks, remember the build-dep - it can sometimes save you a lot of time :)

Comment: I am compiling the program from source though

Comment: It doesn't matter - all `apt-cache build-dep` does is install the build prerequisites for the package of your choice. In this case by installing just libssl-dev, you've completed this step manually. For such trivial cases it's simple but sometimes you might spend much more time trying to figure out what libraries are needed for your code to compile.